# Struts2 Cron Jobs

Tags: struts2, cron

Using struts2, is there a way to trigger an action to occur at specified intervals?

Currently I am writing action classes that perform tasks that need to run at specified intervals and curling the url at the times I need to. Is there a better way to do this than invoking an http request like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.  But you can easily use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), that is *a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java SE application*, probably the most used scheduler in Java environments.

Here is the [quick start Quartz guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/quick_start_guide.html), just in case you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that.